# mysql query is giving error regarding some column that does not exist but it actually does

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to **PHP** and **MySQL** and on *Stackoverflow*, i am working on a code where i need to pull events from database and link the events table with another table called users, i am running the following query but i get the error

```
Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause'
```

my query is as following

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE events.`user_id` = users.`user_id`
```

I am 100% certain that the column user_id exist in table users and not able to figure out why i am getting this error

Comment: You have to add users table in from clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,

```
SELECT * FROM `events` e, `users` u WHERE e.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select from the users table too:

```
SELECT * FROM events,users WHERE events.user_id = users.user_id
```

Comment: thank you, it worked, i did not know i had to mentioned users table before WHERE

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a join.

```
 SELECT * FROM `events`
 LEFT JOIN `users` ON `events`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`
```

Comment: I am not familiar with join yet but thank you, i tried this and it worked

Comment: I use join to get data from two or more related tables. GLWWYAD

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something like:

```
SELECT e.user_id, e.other_column
FROM `events` e JOIN `users` u ON e.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT events.* FROM `events`,`users` WHERE events.`user_id` = users.`user_id`
```